# How to get Package Name / Bundle Identifier of app in IONIC / Cordova (In JavaScript code)

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, plugins, cordova-plugins, bundle-identifier

I need to extract `Package Name` / `Bundle Identifier` of app in `IONIC` / `Cordova app` in my `JavaScript` code.

I have tried using plugins like `$ionicPlatform` & `$cordovaDevice` until now with no help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After searching for hours I couldn't find any plugins for this in IONIC.

There is one in **cordova** which has all properties I needed.

**[cordova-plugin-buildinfo](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-buildinfo)**

> **Installation** : `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-buildinfo`

**Usage :**

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
    console.log('BuildInfo.packageName    =' + BuildInfo.packageName);
    console.log('BuildInfo.basePackageName=' + BuildInfo.basePackageName);
    console.log('BuildInfo.displayName    =' + BuildInfo.displayName);
    console.log('BuildInfo.name           =' + BuildInfo.name);
    console.log('BuildInfo.version        =' + BuildInfo.version);
    console.log('BuildInfo.versionCode    =' + BuildInfo.versionCode);
    console.log('BuildInfo.debug          =' + BuildInfo.debug);
    console.log('BuildInfo.buildType      =' + BuildInfo.buildType);
    console.log('BuildInfo.flavor         =' + BuildInfo.flavor);
}
```

Comment: I had to do something like "let BuildInfo = (<any>window).BuildInfo;" to get this to  work.